# Is a Raku interactive shell available like Bash or Zoiberg shell

Tags: shell, raku, production-environment

Is there a interactive/ login shell for Raku available? I'm looking for a combination an interactive and scripting environment like the [zoid (Zoidberg Shell)](https://metacpan.org/dist/Zoidberg/view/bin/zoid) or Bash.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the Raku REPL? Just type `raku` at your shell prompt: you might be pleasantly surprised. https://course.raku.org/essentials/running-programs/from-repl/

Comment: »ö« .oO ( "Jan 1st 2025: Sysadmins discuss `trapezoid`, @huckfinn's `zoid` descendant as first released in its `zoidtoo` `0.1` form with the help of the Rakoon community 3 years ago today."  `Inline::Perl5`/`Inline::Perl6` support `perl` in `raku` & vice-versa.  Is/was `zoidtoo` `0.1` a `raku` prog that: uses `zoid`; defines a Raku function `z` that processes a block to map Raku to `zoid` features, passing some thru via `Inline::Perl`; and then calls `zoid`?  Is `trapezoid` a descendant that uses the same approach to support PLs like Python via Raku's `Inline::Python`? )

Comment: @raiph Could you let us know what's missing? I can open the Raku REPL and peruse files on my local filesystem. I can execute Raku code on a regex-defined series of filenames (similar to globbing but more precise). I can store data in Raku arrays, etc., and then write them to files. Can you explain what more functionality is required? Thx! [ Ref:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675007/227738 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676629/227738 https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400187/7270649

Comment: Rakudoweekley did mention such a project [Weekly](https://rakudoweekly.blog/2020/04/20/2020-16-rash-in-progress/).

Comment: @jubilatious1 Good comments!  `zoid` README says "aspires to be a fully operational login shell". Here are some basic "litmus tests" and what I assume you mean: Set an env var for session: `%*ENV<foo>=42`. List files: `q:x 'ls'`. Make/change dir: `mkdir 'bar'`/`chdir 'bar'`. Echo to file: `spurt 'foo', 'ls'`. chmod to exec: `chmod 0o755, 'foo'`. Right?  `zoid` doc says "aimed at creating an easy to use interface". Would you say my litmus test examples, and other cases, are as easy as `zoid`? If not:  Maybe a `trapezoid` along lines of `raku -Mzoid:from<Perl5>` etc would be good?

Comment: @jubilatious1 I'd upvote an answer by you explaining your perspective. You could outline what vanilla `raku` REPL provides (eg command line history via readline/linenoise or whatever, and so on); show basic usage (eg my examples); mention creating a file of `sub`s and starting Raku with `raku -Mmyshellstuff` or whatever; briefly comment on the `rash` and `LREP` options mentioned in the current two answers; discuss/link highlights of [shell related `[raku]` SO Q+As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braku%5D+shell); discuss/link doc and articles (eg your SE unix answers). Make it a goldmine!

Answer (score 4):

This may be of interest as a project for building on.
https://raku-musings.com/rash-index.html

Answer (score 3):

Afraid not, there's no such thing. Just a regular [REPL](https://docs.raku.org/programs/04-running-raku). There's this thing called [LREP](https://github.com/awwaiid/p6-lrep), but I'm not sure how current it is or if it's what you're looking for.